# php: download variable content as file

Tags: php, file, download, attachment

Is the subject possible? I have a script executing. At one point I have a large piece of text in a variable. Could I make it available as a downloadable file without actually writing variable content to disk?

```
<?php
    echo "Hello";
    //how do I make the content of this variable downloadable?
    $download_me = "download me...";
    echo "Bye";
?>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you mean letting the user click a link and have a dialog box pop up to save certain content as a text file:

```
<?php
$download_me = "download me...";
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt");
echo $download_me;
?>
```

Is that what you're aiming at?  Also, you might want to write a few lines that only allows the headers to be sent this way if a certain `$_POST` or `$_GET` variable is set.

Comment: Thanks. But where do I stick my $download_me variable in? I don't have any files like test.txt stored on disk.

Comment: you add the headers than echo. test.txt is the filename the user sees, not a file on the server

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me Sam.  @facha - make sure to accept and close the post out :)

Answer (score 8):

It should look like this:

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: text/plain");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='whatever.txt'");
  echo $your_text;
?>
```

Comment: So, is the answer that I have gone forever into the abyss?  Is there any way to view my answer if I wanted to?

Comment: @d2burke: Your answer still stands, but just the code block was improved (in fact, the code as you gave it doesn't work as it should because of the double quotes). You can click on the link "edited Aug 27 '12 at 15:36" below the answer to see your original answer and exactly what I changed.

Comment: aaahh...i see.  very cool.  i've not seen that view before.  Thanks Serrano